# Creating a (ES6) promise without starting to resolve it

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Using ES6 promises, how do I create a promise without defining the logic for resolving it? Here's a basic example (some TypeScript):

```ts
var promises = {};
function waitFor(key: string): Promise<any> {
  if (key in promises) {
    return promises[key];
  }
  var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    // But I don't want to try resolving anything here :(
  });

  promises[key] = promise;
  return promise;
}

function resolveWith(key: string, value: any): void {
  promises[key].resolve(value); // Not valid :(
}
```

It's easily done with other promise libraries. JQuery's for example:

```ts
var deferreds = {};
function waitFor(key: string): Promise<any> {
  if (key in promises) {
    return deferreds[key].promise();
  }
  var def = $.Deferred();    
  deferreds[key] = def;
  return def.promise();
}

function resolveWith(key: string, value: any): void {
  deferreds[key].resolve(value);
}
```

The only way I can see to do this would be to store the resolve function away somewhere within the promise's executor but that seems messy, and I'm not sure it's defined when exactly this function is run - is it always run immediately on construction?

Thanks.

Comment: WTH would you do something like that? A promise without resolve-logic is a forever-pending promise.

Comment: Your second part of the question is a duplicate of [Is JavaScript Promise Callback executed Asynchronosuly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29963129/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi - Imagine something like an asynchronous dependency injection system. You have one part where you're registering injection items, and others where you're requesting them. If I request an item that hasn't been registered yet, then I'll want to return a promise that'll resolve once it has.

Comment: See also the possible duplicate [Promises for promises that are yet to be created without using the deferred \[anti\]pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37426037/1048572)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Good question!

The resolver passed to the promise constructor intentionally runs synchronous in order to support this use case:

```
var deferreds = [];
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    deferreds.push({resolve: resolve, reject: reject});
});
```

Then, at some later point in time:

```
 deferreds[0].resolve("Hello"); // resolve the promise with "Hello"
```

The reason the promise constructor is given is that:

- Typically (but not always) resolution logic is bound to the creation.
- The promise constructor is throw safe and converts exceptions to rejections.

Sometimes it doesn't fit and for that it the resolver runs synchronously. [Here is related reading on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963129/is-javascript-promise-callback-executed-asynchronosuly).

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `Promise.resolve` and storing the bound `then`. But, this looks clean and I am not even sure if the bound `then` will work.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the incredibly fast and thorough answer! Do you happen to have a source stating that executor (the function with the resolve and reject arguments) always runs synchronously at the time of construction?

Comment: @thefourtheye bound `then`s would not work if you don't implement your own `then` function.

Comment: @Barguast sure, for ES6 in particular - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-newpromisecapability is how promises are constructed, which calls http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-construct is called synchronously. It is in turn called synchronously from http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-executor - I think the old https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec is a better source.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Just point to [Is JavaScript Promise Callback executed Asynchronosuly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29963129/1048572) :-)

Comment: @Bergi oh nifty! I completely forgot about that - I'll add a link to it thanks.

Comment: Is assigning the `new Promise` to a variable (`var p`) necessary?

Comment: @papiro no, it is only there as a didactic step to show that you get the promise returned and can use it as a regular promise. It is not necessary though I can't really think about what you can accomplish without using the actual promise in some way.

Comment: If you have multiple promises, it sounds like this method runs them all together because by calling `var p = new Promise`, the promise starts its execution. Looks like you are synchronizing their resolution (end of execution) not the start of execution.

Comment: It should be the part of Promise API with the special state.

Comment: @EugeneHoza it used to be (a long time ago) but it was changed to the revealing constructor pattern (which was considered safer). I used to love it - but in retrospect I'm not sure it's actually safer - it's just a tradeoff. You can read about it here: https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/ - in addition if you feel passionately about it (after you've read the relevant background of course) - you're very welcome to make a suggestion to TC39 to introduce another API.

Answer (score 74):

I want to add my 2 cents here. Considering exactly the question "**Creating a es6 Promise without starting resolve it**" I solved it creating a wrapper function and calling the wrapper function instead. Code:

Let's say we have a function `f` which returns a Promise

```
/** @return Promise<any> */
function f(args) {
   return new Promise(....)
}

// calling f()
f('hello', 42).then((response) => { ... })
```

---

Now, I want to ***prepare*** a call to `f('hello', 42)` without actually solving it:

```
const task = () => f('hello', 42) // not calling it actually

// later
task().then((response) => { ... })
```

Hope this will help someone :)

---

Referencing `Promise.all()` as asked in the comments (and answered by @Joe Frambach), if I want to ***prepare*** a call to `f1('super')` & `f2('rainbow')`, 2 functions that return promises

```
const f1 = args => new Promise( ... )
const f2 = args => new Promise( ... )

const tasks = [
  () => f1('super'),
  () => f2('rainbow')
]

// later
Promise.all(tasks.map(t => t()))
  .then(resolvedValues => { ... })
```

Comment: How can this be used with `Promise.all()` ?

Comment: tasks = [() => f(1), () => f(2)]; Promise.all(tasks.map(t => t())).then(...

Comment: @Frondor I also came here wanting to use promises in my `redux saga` unit testion. by creating a curried function. `function*f()` which is way of still during `expectSaga()` unit testing. f() -> g() -> Promise

Comment: In combination with await this is exactly what I needed to setup tasks and then wait for them all to finish. So in my case the last line becomes:

await Promise.all(tasks.map(t => t()));

Answer (score 5):

Things are slowly getting better in JavaScript land, but this is one case where things are still unnecessarily complicated. Here's a simple helper to expose the resolve and reject functions:

```
Promise.unwrapped = () => {
  let resolve, reject, promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve, reject = _reject
  })
  promise.resolve = resolve, promise.reject = reject
  return promise
}

// a contrived example

let p = Promise.unwrapped()
p.then(v => alert(v))
p.resolve('test')
```

Apparently there used to be a [`Promise.defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred) helper, but even that insisted on the deferred object being separate from the promise itself...

Answer (score 3):

How about a more comprehensive approach?

You could write a Constructor that returns a new Promise decorated with `.resolve()` and `.reject()` methods.

You would probably choose to name the constructor `Deferred` - a term with a lot of precedence in [the history of] javascript promises.

```
function Deferred(fn) {
    fn = fn || function(){};

    var resolve_, reject_;

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve_ = resolve;
        reject_ = reject;
        fn(resolve, reject);
    });

    promise.resolve = function(val) {
        (val === undefined) ? resolve_() : resolve_(val);
        return promise;//for chainability
    }
    promise.reject = function(reason) {
        (reason === undefined) ? reject_() : reject_(reason);
        return promise;//for chainability
    }
    promise.promise = function() {
        return promise.then(); //to derive an undecorated promise (expensive but simple).
    }

    return promise;
}
```

By returning a decorated promsie rather than a plain object, all the promise's natural methods/properties remain available in addition to the decorations.

Also, by handling `fn`, the revealer pattern remains availble, should you need/choose to use it on a Deferred.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7e3c5r1e/)**

Now, with the `Deferred()` utility in place, your code is virtually identical to the jQuery example.

```
var deferreds = {};
function waitFor(key: string): Promise<any> {
  if (key in promises) {
    return deferreds[key].promise();
  }
  var def = Deferred();    
  deferreds[key] = def;
  return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: I don't know, this seems to re-introduce all the things that we wanted to avoid when switching from deferreds to promises and the constructor approach. Also, your implementation is totally overcomplicated, and contains a few mistakes: a) if you give `Deferred` a callback parameter, it should be called back with the deferred b) testing the `value`/`reason` for `undefined` is absolutely unnecessary c) `.resolve` and `.reject` never need to be chained d) your `.promise` method doesn't return an undecorated promise

Comment: I've always been uneasy about designing out Deferreds. I'm sure they are rare but there must be usage cases when a Deferred is necessary - ie when the means for settlement cannot be defined at the time a Promise is created.  I don't understand (a), I'm open to persuasion on (b) and you're certainly right about (c).

Comment: I mean that you should do `fn(promise)` (or rather, `fn(deferred)` actually) instead of `fn(resolve, reject)`. Yes, I can certainly see a need for "resolver objects" that can be stored somewhere and expose `.fulfill` and `.reject` methods, but I think those should not implement the promise interface.

Comment: @Bergi, I understand that jQuery, for example, reveals the Deferred itself as a callback arg. Maybe I'm missing something but I can't see why a Deferred implementation *shouldn't* mimic the de facto practice for `new Promise(fn)` of revealing just `resolve` and `reject`.

Comment: Also, whereas the `when.js` documentation discourages use of its `when.defer`, it does acknowledge that `in certain (rare) scenarios it can be convenient to have access to both the promise and it's associated resolving functions`. If that statement is to be believed, then what I'm offering above should seem reasonable (in rare scenarios).

Comment: I just think you just shouldn't do both. Either you return a deferred that exposes the resolver functions as methods and the associated promise (as it is sometimes convenient indeed), *or* you use the standard practise of passing separate `resolve` and `reject` function to the callback. If you really want to do both deferreds and a callback, please at least don't mix the approaches, and follow jQuery's example of passing the deferred to the closure scope.

Comment: Well that's all food for thought and you do seem to stop short of saying that what I'm offering here is wrong.

Comment: Yes, after you've fixed the mistake with the `.promise()` method, the solution no more *wrong*, but I still do think that it is not useful. It goes against my subjective idea of good practises.

Comment: Where is the `promises` variable declared? What it holds?

Comment: @Marecky, the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7e3c5r1e/) should be enough to explain that.

Answer (score 3):

What makes this kind of issues look complicated is the procedural nature of Javascript I guess. To resolve this, I created a simple class. Here how it looks:

```js
class PendingPromise {

    constructor(args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    execute() {
        return new Promise(this.args);
    }
}
```

This promise will only be executed when you call `execute()`. For example:

```js
function log() {
    return new PendingPromise((res, rej) => {
        console.log("Hello, World!");
    });
}

log().execute();
```

Comment: Quite simple and genius! Thank you! This also does not require any temporary variables like `deferreds` mentioned in some other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [p-lazy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-lazy), and create your promise like this:

```js
import DeferredPromise from 'p-lazy';

const lazyPromise = new DeferredPromise(async (resolve)=> {
    await someHeavyOperation();
    resolve('ok');
});

// `someHeavyOperation` is not yet called

await lazyPromise; // `someHeavyOperation` is called
```

Try it out.

Answer (score -1):

[CPomise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) allows you to resolve your promises outside, but this is an antipattern since it breaks Promise incapsulation model. ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-external-resolve-bc4hg?file=/src/index.js))

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

const promise = new CPromise(() => {});

promise.then((value) => console.log(`Done: ${value}`)); //123

setTimeout(() => promise.resolve(123));
```