# JavaScript ES6 promise for loop

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeout = Math.random() * 1000;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(i);
        }, timeout);
    });

    // TODO: Chain this promise to the previous one (maybe without having it running?)
}
```

The above will give the following random output:

```
6
9
4
8
5
1
7
2
3
0
```

The task is simple: Make sure each promise runs only after the other one (`.then()`).

For some reason, I couldn't find a way to do it.

I tried generator functions (`yield`), tried simple functions that return a promise, but at the end of the day it always comes down to the same problem: **The loop is synchronous**.

With [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) I'd simply use `async.series()`.

How do you solve it?

Comment: Related: [Creating a (ES6) promise without starting to resolve it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31069453/11683)

Answer (score 516, accepted):

As you already hinted in your question, your code creates all promises synchronously. Instead they should only be created at the time the preceding one resolves.

Secondly, each promise that is created with `new Promise` needs to be resolved with a call to `resolve` (or `reject`). This should be done when the timer expires. That will trigger any `then` callback you would have on that promise. And such a `then` callback (or `await`) is a necessity in order to implement the chain.

With those ingredients, there are several ways to perform this asynchronous chaining:

1. With a `for` loop that starts with an immediately resolving promise
2. With `Array#reduce` that starts with an immediately resolving promise
3. With a function that passes itself as resolution callback
4. With ECMAScript2017's [`async` / `await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
5. With ECMAScript2020's [`for await...of` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

But let me first introduce a very useful, generic function.

#### Promisfying `setTimeout`

Using `setTimeout` is fine, but we actually need a promise that resolves when the timer expires. So let's create such a function: this is called *promisifying* a function, in this case we will promisify `setTimeout`. It will improve the readability of the code, and can be used for all of the above options:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

See a snippet and comments for each of the options below.

#### 1. With `for`

You *can* use a `for` loop, but you must make sure it doesn't create all promises synchronously. Instead you create an initial immediately resolving promise, and then chain new promises as the previous ones resolve:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
    p = p.then(() => delay(Math.random() * 1000))
         .then(() => console.log(i));
}
```

So this code creates one long chain of `then` calls. The variable `p` only serves to not lose track of that chain, and allow a next iteration of the loop to continue on the same chain. The callbacks will start executing after the synchronous loop has completed.

It is important that the `then`-callback *returns* the promise that `delay()` creates: this will ensure the asynchronous chaining.

#### 2. With `reduce`

This is just a more functional approach to the previous strategy. You create an array with the same length as the chain you want to execute, and start out with an immediately resolving promise:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

[...Array(10)].reduce( (p, _, i) => 
    p.then(() => delay(Math.random() * 1000))
     .then(() => console.log(i))
, Promise.resolve() );
```

This is probably more useful when you actually *have* an array with data to be used in the promises.

#### 3. With a function passing itself as resolution-callback

Here we create a function and call it immediately. It creates the first promise synchronously. When it resolves, the function is called again:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(function loop(i) {
    if (i >= 10) return; // all done
    delay(Math.random() * 1000).then(() => {
        console.log(i);
        loop(i+1);
    });
})(0);
```

This creates a function named `loop`, and at the very end of the code you can see it gets called immediately with argument 0. This is the counter, and the *i* argument. The function will create a new promise if that counter is still below 10, otherwise the chaining stops.

When `delay()` resolves, it will trigger the `then` callback which will call the function again.

#### 4. With `async`/`await`

Modern JS engines [support this syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility):

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function loop() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await delay(Math.random() * 1000);
        console.log(i);
    }
})();
```

It may look strange, as it *seems* like the promises are created synchronously, but in reality the `async` function *returns* when it executes the first `await`. Every time an awaited promise resolves, the function's running context is restored, and proceeds after the `await`, until it encounters the next one, and so it continues until the loop finishes.

#### 5. With `for await...of`

With EcmaScript 2020, the [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) found its way to modern JavaScript engines. Although it does not really reduce code in this case, it allows to isolate the definition of the random interval chain from the actual iteration of it:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function * randomDelays(count, max) {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) yield delay(Math.random() * max).then(() => i);
}

(async function loop() {
    for await (let i of randomDelays(10, 1000)) console.log(i);
})();
```

Comment: I just wonder how this guy was able to come up with so many solutions.

Comment: the last method of is perfect, we just have to add `async` with the outer function and `await` with `Promises` inside the loop

Comment: @trincot thank you so very much! This answer has helped me immensely to better understand Promises

Comment: @VinKrish And to think that this question is marked as duplicate, and could have as well been closed. Long live moderation :/

Comment: @user776686, it *has* been closed a long time ago. If you check the history of the duplicate reference, you can see that it was edited from a very specific Q-library question to something that indeed made this one look as a duplicate. Think about it what you may... there are sometimes subjective things happening on this site.

Comment: @trincot This is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `async/await` for this. I would explain more, but there's nothing really to it. It's just a regular `for` loop but I added the `await` keyword before the construction of your Promise

What I like about this is your Promise can resolve a normal value instead of having a side effect like your code (or other answers here) include. This gives you powers like in *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past* where you can affect things in both the Light World *and* the Dark World – ie, you can easily work with data before/after the Promised data is available without having to resort to deeply nested functions, other unwieldy control structures, or stupid [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)s.

```
// where DarkWorld is in the scary, unknown future
// where LightWorld is the world we saved from Ganondorf
LightWorld ... await DarkWorld
```

So here's what that will look like ...

```js
async function someProcedure (n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const t = Math.random() * 1000
    const x = await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t, i))
    console.log (i, x)
  }
  return 'done'
}

someProcedure(10)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
done
```

See how we don't have to deal with that bothersome `.then` call within our procedure? And `async` keyword will automatically ensure that a `Promise` is returned, so we can chain a `.then` call on the returned value. This sets us up for great success: run the sequence of `n` Promises, *then* do something important – like display a success/error message.

Comment: await new Promise is not valid

Comment: @AndroidDev I don't know if it's an actual ecmascript syntax violation, but it's working here in `Chrome 58` – brackets like `await (expr)` can be used to resolve ambiguity otherwise. I updated the question to include a working code snippet.

Comment: @AndroidDev, your claim is false.

Comment: This would be fantastic if you could write it as a *named function*, then I'd definitely up-vote it.

Comment: John, the function above _is_ named. `someProcedure.name` returns `"someProcedure"`. what you probably mean is a _function declaration_. The transformation is simple: change `const someProcedure = async n => ...` to `async function someProcedure (n) ...`

Comment: @Thankyou This is pretty sexy ^^

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what are the possible pitfalls?

Comment: @DanubioMüller of using `async` and `await`? some old browsers don't support them

Comment: You are using async/await, instead of *only* the mentioned promises (also in the question's tags). We can't give for granted that the OP has support for `await` syntax; even if I agree it would make things easier & clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the excellent answer by trincot, I wrote a reusable function that accepts a handler to run over each item in an array. The function itself returns a promise that allows you to wait until the loop has finished and the handler function that you pass may also return a promise.

## loop(items, handler) : Promise

It took me some time to get it right, but I believe the following code will be usable in a lot of promise-looping situations.

**Copy-paste ready code:**

```
// SEE https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295049/286685
const loop = (arr, fn, busy, err, i=0) => {
  const body = (ok,er) => {
    try {const r = fn(arr[i], i, arr); r && r.then ? r.then(ok).catch(er) : ok(r)}
    catch(e) {er(e)}
  }
  const next = (ok,er) => () => loop(arr, fn, ok, er, ++i)
  const run  = (ok,er) => i < arr.length ? new Promise(body).then(next(ok,er)).catch(er) : ok()
  return busy ? run(busy,err) : new Promise(run)
}
```

## Usage

To use it, call it with the array to loop over as the first argument and the handler function as the second. Do not pass parameters for the third, fourth and fifth arguments, they are used internally.

```js
const loop = (arr, fn, busy, err, i=0) => {
  const body = (ok,er) => {
    try {const r = fn(arr[i], i, arr); r && r.then ? r.then(ok).catch(er) : ok(r)}
    catch(e) {er(e)}
  }
  const next = (ok,er) => () => loop(arr, fn, ok, er, ++i)
  const run  = (ok,er) => i < arr.length ? new Promise(body).then(next(ok,er)).catch(er) : ok()
  return busy ? run(busy,err) : new Promise(run)
}

const items = ['one', 'two', 'three']

loop(items, item => {
  console.info(item)
})
.then(() => console.info('Done!'))
```

## Advanced use cases

Let's look at the handler function, nested loops and error handling.

### handler(current, index, all)

The handler gets passed 3 arguments. The current item, the index of the current item and the complete array being looped over. If the handler function needs to do async work, it can return a promise and the loop function will wait for the promise to resolve before starting the next iteration. You can nest loop invocations and all works as expected.

```js
const loop = (arr, fn, busy, err, i=0) => {
  const body = (ok,er) => {
    try {const r = fn(arr[i], i, arr); r && r.then ? r.then(ok).catch(er) : ok(r)}
    catch(e) {er(e)}
  }
  const next = (ok,er) => () => loop(arr, fn, ok, er, ++i)
  const run  = (ok,er) => i < arr.length ? new Promise(body).then(next(ok,er)).catch(er) : ok()
  return busy ? run(busy,err) : new Promise(run)
}

const tests = [
  [],
  ['one', 'two'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C']
]

loop(tests, (test, idx, all) => new Promise((testNext, testFailed) => {
  console.info('Performing test ' + idx)
  return loop(test, (testCase) => {
    console.info(testCase)
  })
  .then(testNext)
  .catch(testFailed)
}))
.then(() => console.info('All tests done'))
```

### Error handling

Many promise-looping examples I looked at break down when an exception occurs. Getting this function to do the right thing was pretty tricky, but as far as I can tell it is working now. Make sure to add a catch handler to any inner loops and invoke the rejection function when it happens. E.g.:

```js
const loop = (arr, fn, busy, err, i=0) => {
  const body = (ok,er) => {
    try {const r = fn(arr[i], i, arr); r && r.then ? r.then(ok).catch(er) : ok(r)}
    catch(e) {er(e)}
  }
  const next = (ok,er) => () => loop(arr, fn, ok, er, ++i)
  const run  = (ok,er) => i < arr.length ? new Promise(body).then(next(ok,er)).catch(er) : ok()
  return busy ? run(busy,err) : new Promise(run)
}

const tests = [
  [],
  ['one', 'two'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C']
]

loop(tests, (test, idx, all) => new Promise((testNext, testFailed) => {
  console.info('Performing test ' + idx)
  loop(test, (testCase) => {
    if (idx == 2) throw new Error()
    console.info(testCase)
  })
  .then(testNext)
  .catch(testFailed)  //  <--- DON'T FORGET!!
}))
.then(() => console.error('Oops, test should have failed'))
.catch(e => console.info('Succesfully caught error: ', e))
.then(() => console.info('All tests done'))
```

## UPDATE: NPM package

Since writing this answer, I turned the above code in an NPM package.

### [for-async](https://npmjs.com/package/for-async)

### Install

```
npm install --save for-async
```

### Import

```
var forAsync = require('for-async');  // Common JS, or
import forAsync from 'for-async';
```

### Usage (async)

```
var arr = ['some', 'cool', 'array'];
forAsync(arr, function(item, idx){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.info(item, idx);
      // Logs 3 lines: `some 0`, `cool 1`, `array 2`
      resolve(); // <-- signals that this iteration is complete
    }, 25); // delay 25 ms to make async
  })
})
```

See the package readme for more details.

Comment: would be good to add some comments to the loop function ..

Comment: @kofifus Yes you are right. Since I wrote this answer, I actually turned this code into a documented NPM project. I will add the link to the answer.

Comment: ok the code there seems totally different than this one ...

Comment: @kofifus Yeah I rewrote it. I like rewriting code and trying to improve it further  :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solves my problem

Comment: Can you tell me how to use it in JS object? I've tried the js object but it doesn't work

Comment: You'll have to clarify your question further @ViniciusPaldês. What are you trying to do? `forEach` normally works on arrays and so does the code in this answer. If you want to loop over all keys of an object, you can get those keys into an array with `Object.keys(myObject)`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are limited to ES6, the best option is Promise all. `Promise.all(array)` also returns an array of promises after successfully executing all the promises in `array` argument.
Suppose, if you want to update many student records in the database, the following code demonstrates the concept of Promise.all in such case-

```js
let promises = students.map((student, index) => {
    //where students is a db object
    student.rollNo = index + 1;
    student.city = 'City Name';
    //Update whatever information on student you want
    return student.save();
});
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    //All the save queries will be executed when .then is executed
    //You can do further operations here after as all update operations are completed now
});
```

Map is just an example method for loop. You can also use `for` or `forin` or `forEach` loop. So the concept is pretty simple, start the loop in which you want to do bulk async operations. Push every such async operation statement in an array declared outside the scope of that loop. After the loop completes, execute the Promise all statement with the prepared array of such queries/promises as argument.

The basic concept is that the javascript loop is synchronous whereas database call is async and we use push method in loop that is also sync. So, the problem of asynchronous behavior doesn't occur inside the loop.

Comment: Why use `map` if you're just treating it like a *forEach* and not going to store the results?  Why not assign the map to `promises` and avoid the `push` within?

Comment: The OP's requirement was to *"...Make sure each promise runs only after the other one..."*.

Comment: @vol7ron I admit I'm also guilty to using `map` i.s.o. `forEach`... It's shorter to type and the runtime performance difference ususlly is not important in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working attempt using recursion:

```
function promisesWithRecursion() {
    const urlArray = [myUrl1, myUrl2, myUrl3]; //... and many more
    let i = 0;
    let call = ( () => fetch(urlArray[i], { method: "GET"})
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        //onSuccess()
        //console.log("response: " + text);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text;
        if(text.includes("ERROR")) {
            console.log("Error in url index " + i);
            console.log(urlArray[i]);
            return null;
        } else {
            nextUrl = urlArray[++i] ? urlArray[i] : null;
            if(!nextUrl) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return call();
            }
        }
    }
    )
    .catch(console.error.bind(console))
    );
    call();
}
```

This way promises are executed one after another and the calls are blocked if errors are thrown; I also tried with for loops like

```
let prom = Promise.resolve();
for (const url of urlArray) {
    prom.then(() => fetch(url, { method: "GET"})
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text;
        if(text.includes("ERROR")) {
            break;
        }
    }).catch(...) );
}
```

or

```
for (let i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) ...
```

but I can't make it work, they are all fired off in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

here's my 2 cents worth:

- resuable function `forpromise()`
- emulates a classic for loop
- allows for early exit based on internal logic, returning a value
- can collect an array of results passed into resolve/next/collect
- defaults to start=0,increment=1
- exceptions thrown inside loop are caught and passed to .catch()

```js
    function forpromise(lo, hi, st, res, fn) {
        if (typeof res === 'function') {
            fn = res;
            res = undefined;
        }
        if (typeof hi === 'function') {
            fn = hi;
            hi = lo;
            lo = 0;
            st = 1;
        }
        if (typeof st === 'function') {
            fn = st;
            st = 1;
        }
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            (function loop(i) {
                if (i >= hi) return resolve(res);
                const promise = new Promise(function(nxt, brk) {
                    try {
                        fn(i, nxt, brk);
                    } catch (ouch) {
                        return reject(ouch);
                    }
                });
                promise.
                catch (function(brkres) {
                    hi = lo - st;
                    resolve(brkres)
                }).then(function(el) {
                    if (res) res.push(el);
                    loop(i + st)
                });
            })(lo);

        });
    }


    //no result returned, just loop from 0 thru 9
    forpromise(0, 10, function(i, next) {
        console.log("iterating:", i);
        next();
    }).then(function() {


        console.log("test result 1", arguments);

        //shortform:no result returned, just loop from 0 thru 4
        forpromise(5, function(i, next) {
            console.log("counting:", i);
            next();
        }).then(function() {

            console.log("test result 2", arguments);



            //collect result array, even numbers only
            forpromise(0, 10, 2, [], function(i, collect) {
                console.log("adding item:", i);
                collect("result-" + i);
            }).then(function() {

                console.log("test result 3", arguments);

                //collect results, even numbers, break loop early with different result
                forpromise(0, 10, 2, [], function(i, collect, break_) {
                    console.log("adding item:", i);
                    if (i === 8) return break_("ending early");
                    collect("result-" + i);
                }).then(function() {

                    console.log("test result 4", arguments);

                    // collect results, but break loop on exception thrown, which we catch
                    forpromise(0, 10, 2, [], function(i, collect, break_) {
                        console.log("adding item:", i);
                        if (i === 4) throw new Error("failure inside loop");
                        collect("result-" + i);
                    }).then(function() {

                        console.log("test result 5", arguments);

                    }).
                    catch (function(err) {

                        console.log("caught in test 5:[Error ", err.message, "]");

                    });

                });

            });


        });



    });
```

Comment: Don't create a `new Promise` inside a `new Promise` callback. It is an amplified case of the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: Also, I thought Promises were intended to avoid a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), but here the nesting becomes deeper with every test...

Answer (score 0):

I see the previous answers and feel confused. And I coded the following by the answers' inspiration. I think its logic is more obvious, I call the function to replace original for loop:

```
async function pointToCountry(world, data) { // Data is for loop array
  if (data.length > 0) { // For condition
    const da = data.shift(); // Get current data and modified data one row code
    // Some business logic
    msg = da.info
    pointofView(world, da);
    // Await the current task
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(_ => {
      r() // Resolve and finish the current task
    }, 5000))
    // Call itself and enter the next loop
    pointToCountry(world, data)
  } else { // Business logic after all tasks
    pointofView(world, { longitude: 0, latitude: 0 });
    world.controls().autoRotate = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using async/await, instead of *only* the mentioned promises (also in the question's tags). We can't give for granted that the OP has support for `await` syntax; even if I agree it would make things easier & clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), you should use 'for await':

```
(async () => {
  for await (const num of asyncIterable) {
    console.log(num);
  }
  // My action here
})();
```

For more information, see this *[for await...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // This is my main function - calculate all project by city
       const projectCity = async (req, res, next) => {
            try {         
                let record = [];            
                let cityList = await Cityodel.find({active:true});
            
                    for (let j = 0; j < cityList.length; j++) {
        
                    let arr = [];
                
                    let projectList   = await getProduct(cityList[j]._id)
        
                    arr.push({
                        _id:cityList[j]._id,
                        name:cityList[j].name,
                        projectList:projectList
                    })
          
                    record.push(arr);                
                }
        
                return res.status(200).send({ 
                    status: CONSTANT.REQUESTED_CODES.SUCCESS,
                    result: record });
            } catch (error) {
                return res.status(400).json(UTILS.errorHandler(error));
            }
        };
            
        
        async function getProduct(city){       
            let projectList = await ProjectModel.find({city:city});      
            return projectList;        
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've created a snippet in Angular that loops a promise function indefinitely. You can start it, stop it, or restart it.

You basically need to recursively call the same method and await it's current process like so:

```
async autoloop(): Promise<void> {
  if(this.running){
    await this.runMe();
    await this.autoloop();
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

JavaScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  messages: string[] = [];
  counter = 1;
  running = false;

  constructor() {
    this.start();
  }

  onClick(): void {
    this.running = !this.running;
    if(this.running){
      this.start();
    }
    else{
      this.stop();
    }
  }

  async onRestartClick(): Promise<void>{
    await this.stop();
    this.messages = [];
    this.counter = 1;
    this.start();
  }

  start(): void{
    this.running = true;
    this.autoloop();
  }
  
  async stop(): Promise<void>{
    this.running = false;
    await this.delay(1000);
  }

  async autoloop(): Promise<void> {
    if(this.running){
      await this.runMe();
      await this.autoloop();
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  async runMe(): Promise<void> {
    await this.delay(1000);
    if(this.running){
      this.messages.push(`Message ${this.counter++}`);
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  async delay(ms: number) {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<h1>Endless looping a promise every 1 second</h1>
<button (click)="onClick()">Start / stop</button>
<button (click)="onRestartClick()">Restart</button>
<p *ngFor="let message of messages">
  {{message}}
</p>
```

Comment: You are using async/await, instead of *only* the mentioned promises (also in the question's tags). We can't give for granted that the OP has support for `await` syntax; even if I agree it would make things easier & clearer.