# How to create a loop of promises

Tags: javascript, promise

so i have a  promise that collects data from a server but only collects 50 responses at a time. i have 250 responses to collect.

i could just concate promises together like below

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(getResults.get())
    })
    .then((results) => {
    totalResults.concat(results)
    return getResults.get()
    })
    .then((results) => {
    totalResults.concat(results)
    return getResults.get()
    }).then((results) => {
     totalResults.concat(results)
    return getResults.get()
    })
```

In this instance i only need 250 results so this seems a managable solution but is there a way of concating promises in a loop. so i run a loop 5 times and each time run the next promise.

Sorry i am new to promises and if this were callbacks this is what i would do.

Comment: Does `get` return a promise?

Comment: I would recommend checking out the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library for this. It'll make your life way easier. Look at the `async.eachLimit` functionality.

Comment: @forrestmid No, that does not work well with promises.

Comment: Use recursion with promises. Or `async`/`await` if you insist on a loop.

Comment: _How to create a loop of promises_ -> Get married?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to loop and serialise the promises, not executing any other `get` calls once one fails, then try this loop:

```
async function getAllResults() {  // returns a promise for 250 results
    let totalResults = [];
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            totalResults.push(...await getResults.get());
        }
    } catch(e) {};
    return totalResults;
}
```

This uses the EcmaScript2017 `async` and `await` syntax. When not available, chain the promises with `then`:

```
function getAllResults() {
    let totalResults = [];
    let prom = Promise.resolve([]);
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        prom = prom.then(results => {
            totalResults = totalResults.concat(results);
            return getResults.get();
        });
    }
    return prom.then(results => totalResults.concat(results));
}
```

Note that you should avoid the [promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). It is not necessary to use `new Promise` here.

Also consider adding a `.catch()` call on the promise returned by the above function, to deal with error conditions.

Finally, be aware that `concat` does not modify the array you call it on. It returns the concatenated array, so you need to assign that return value. In your code you don't assign the return value, so the call has no effect.

See also [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40328932/5459839).

Comment: You might want to start with  `prom = Promise.resolve([])` so that you don't have to duplicate the `get` calls and concatenation, and count to 5 properly.

Comment: thank you this is working nicely. Excellent suggestion

Answer (score 8):

Probably you just need `Promise.all` method.
For every request you should create a promise and put it in an array, then you wrap everything in `all` method and you're done.

Example (assuming that `getResults.get` returns a promise):

```
let promiseChain = [];
for(let i = 0; i <5; i++){
    promiseChain.push(getResults.get());
}

Promise.all(promiseChain)
    .then(callback)
```

You can read more about this method here:
[Promise.all at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

**EDIT**
You can access data returned by the promises this way:

```
function callback(data){
    doSomething(data[0]) //data from the first promise in the chain
    ...
    doEventuallySomethingElse(data[4]) //data from the last promise
}
```

Comment: How would you propose the OP gets the results from the get() calls using this approach?

Comment: thanks but this is returning the same 50 results 5 times

Comment: In this case we need to know the `get` implementation. But if you do not want to have the maximum benefit from the async nature of promises, you could try to serialize the promises using (for example) async. Here's an overview of its functionalities http://caolan.github.io/async/