# How can I check that multiple async operations have completed?

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I have a case where I want to do something once 10 async calls have completed

```
let i = 0;
let array = [];

do {
  this.service.getSomething(i).subscribe(response => {
    array[i] = response;
  });
} while (i < 10);

// how can I know when the 10 async calls have completed?
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you tag your question as `javascript`?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether you know the async operations (read Observables/Promises) beforehand or not.

For example if you can compose an array of Observables then the easiest way is to use `forkJoin`:

```
let observables = [ ... ];
Observable.forkJoin(observables)
    .subscribe(results => /* whatever */);
```

Otherwise, you can just `mergeMap` them into a single chain a listen only to the `complete` signal:

```
Observable.range(1, 10) // or whatever
    .mergeMap(i => /* return Observable here */)
    .subscribe(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('all done'));
```

Answer (score 1):

'The Rx way' is to use [forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md):

```
const requestParams = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const requests = requestParams.map(i => this.service.getSomething(i));
Observable.forkJoin(requests).subscribe(reponseArray => alldone(responseArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your loop asynchronous, so that an iteration will only occur when the next response is available. Here is how you can do that:

```
(function loop(arr) {
    if (arr.length >= 10) return alldone(array); // all done
    this.service.getSomething(arr.length).subsribe(response => {
        loop(array.concat(response)); // "recursive" call
    });
})([]); // <--- pass empty array as argument to the loop function

function alldone(arr) {
    console.log(arr);
}
```

The `loop` function is immediately invoked with an empty array as argument. When you get the response, you call that function again, now with the extended array, ...etc. Once you have 10 responses, you call another function that will do something with the final array.

As you can see, I chose to eliminate the variable `i`, since `arr.length` has the same value.

Note that this kind of asynchronous processing can also be done with promises and some recent features like `async` and `await`. You might want to look into that. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329190/5459839)

Answer (score 0):

You can just count responses in separate variable, and check it before continue:

```
let i = 0;
let array = [];
var finishedCnt=0;
do {
  this.service.getSomething(i).subsribe(response => {
    array[i] = response;
    finishedCnt++;
    if(finishedCnt>=10) {
        // all requests done, do something here
    }
  });
} while (i < 10);
```