# For loop inside promises chained in transaction in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I am building a nodeJS, hapiJS and Sequelize (with PostgreSQL) application and have some issues when I'm using a for loop inside a promise chained in a transaction with Sequelize.

I would like to query my database with different content inside a contents list.

I have founded some solutions with Promises.all() or Promise.map() but I cannot apply this to my problem.

Can anyone explain me the right direction?

```
db.User.sequelize.transaction(function(t){
         return db.User.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                name: request.payload.user.id
            },
            transaction: t
        })
        .then( userResult => {
            return db.Order.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    userId : userResult[0].dataValues.userId,
                    code : request.payload.order.code,
                    brand : request.payload.order.brand,
                    date : request.payload.date
                },
                transaction: t
            })
        })
        // ############## HERE ##################
        .then( orderResult => {
            console.log("I WILL BE PRINTED")
            for (var i = 0; i < request.payload.content; i++){
                console.log("I WILL NOT BE PRINTED")
                db.Product.findOrCreate({
                    where :{ean : request.payload.content[i].product.ean},
                    transaction: t  // FAIRE BOUCLE CONTENT
                })
                .then( productResult => {
                    return db.Info.findOrCreate({
                        where: {
                            //TODO : prefix et password
                            productId: productResult[0].dataValues.productId,
                            orderId: orderResult[0].dataValues.orderId
                        }
                    }).then( infoResult => {
                        console.log(productResult)
                        return db.Range.create({
                            infoId : infoResult[0].dataValues.infoId,
                            low : productResult[0].dataValues.offset,
                            high : request.payload.content[i].quantity
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        })
        .then(res => { return console.log("ok")})
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop)

Comment: If the `console.log` inside of the loop does not show up, then one problem is with the condition of the loop. But you need to solve it with `Promise.all` or `Promise.map`. Why do you think that they cannot be applied to your problem?

Comment: @t.niese I meant that i did not succed in applying them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that you never create a promise in the first place. Your loop doesn't return a promise at all and `Promise.all` fires back only when all promises are resolved.

Since you are using es6 syntax you might as well use the `map` method instead of a `for` loop. It is a more functionnal approach.

It would result in something like:

```
Promise.all(request.payload.content.map(content => {
    db.Product.findOrCreate({
        where :{ean : content.product.ean},
        transaction: t
    })
})
```

If you prefer to stick to the for loop the strategy is the same. Wrap your loop in `promise.all` which will store all the returned promises by your query in an array. When the loop ends and all promises are resolved, `promise.all` will be triggered. Note that if a single promise is rejected, `promise.all` will be rejected

Comment: You call `resolve()` before the async call of `findOrCreate` is finished. And `findOrCreate` already returns a Promise, so there is no need to wrap it into another Promise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it works! You should edit the line `where :{ean : request.payload.content[i].product.ean}` by `where :{ean : content.product.ean}`

Comment: Glad it helped you! You're right I just copy pasted your loop and didn't change the core, forgot about that, thanks!