# Convert from Callback hell to promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have been learning how to use callback with stupid callback hell.

This is an example I have created: https://jsfiddle.net/1donpcvv/

It is working as expected. `step1()` has to complete first and then move on to `step2()` and then finally `step3()`

I am trying to convert to promise which I am struggling to get it work. What did I do wrong?

JS:

```
function step1() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 1 done After 3 seconds");
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function step2() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 2 done After 2 seconds");
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function step3() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 3 done After 1 seconds");
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Usage

```
step1().then().step2().then().step3();
```

Comment: `async function run() {
      await step1();
      await step2();
      await step3();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for chaining promises is:

```
step1().then(step2).then(step3);
```

... so you provide callback arguments to `then`.

In less trivial cases where you maybe use the promised value and/or arguments, you could use `bind` or inline function expressions:

```
step1().then(result => step2(result)).then(result2 => step3(result2));
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was almost there. Thats nice. Is there a way without adding `new Promise()` on each step method?

Comment: Sure, just promisify `setTimeout`, like I described in the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329190/5459839).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to `async/await` syntax

```js
async function bar () {
    await step1();
    await step2();
    await step3();
}

bar()
  .then(() => {/*After bar execution here*/})
  .catch(err => console.error('some step reject', err))

function step1() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 1 done After 3 seconds");
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function step2() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 2 done After 2 seconds");
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function step3() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 3 done After 1 seconds");
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

You can manage rejects with `try...catch`

```
async function bar () {
    try {
        await step1();
        await step2();
        await step3();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('some step reject', e)
    }
}
```

and bar is like

```
bar().then(() => {/*After bar execution here*/})
```

or

```
async function foo () {
    await bar()
}
```