# Promise in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have some struggles with a foreach loop. This is my situation:
I have some elements in an object array. I need to perform 2 queries per object. Than I need the next object and do the same etc.

I have made 2 methods for the query:

```
function insertObj(locationId, cartId, quantity){
        return models.orders_cart.create({
            quantity: quantity,
            cartId: cartId,
            locationId: locationId,
        });
    }

function insertObj2(locationId, cartId, quantity){
    return models.orders_cart.create({
        quantity: quantity,
        cartId: cartId,
        locationId: locationId,
    });
}
```

.create returns a promise, so I can use then. This is my foreach loop.

```
locations.forEach(function (element) {

});
```

I need both methods in there. Waiting on the result and go to the next iteration. I really don't know how to do it properly with promises.

Comment: You need an async generator (if you are working with babel)

Comment: You [cannot use `forEach` with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi is there a other way to do it?

Comment: @da1lbi3 [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop), but none uses `forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use async-await this will do the trick:

```
async runAsync(locations){
  for(let location of locations){
    await something();
    await something1();
  };
}
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't wait between iterations, or even allows waiting for the complete loop

Comment: Try using for..of instead of forEach method, there was some issue with this method.