# Wait for async method in for loop in Cypress

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cypress

Edit: Why this is not a duplicate: because **Cypress**, just read instead of tagging everything as duplicate.

Edit 2: Also, see answer for better understanding of the differences between usual async `for` loops problems and this question.

---

I am writing cypress tests and I want to create a cypress command that populates my database with a list of users. I want the creation loop to wait for each user to be created before it moves on to the next one (because I want that done in a specific order).

For now, my loop looks like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("populateDb", (users) => {
  var createdItems = []

  for (const user of users) {
    cy.createUser(user, 'passe').then(response => {
      createdUsers.unshift(response.body.user)
    })
  }
  return createdItems
})
```

Of course, this loop does not wait for each user to be created before moving onto the next one (I want 'sequential treatment', **NOT** 'parallel and then wait for all promise to resolve')

I have read the answers about async for-loop here:

- [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop)
- [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

But I can't seem to find what I want, mainly because cypress wont allow me to declare my function as async as follow :

```
Cypress.Commands.add("populateDb", async (users) => {
    //Some code
})
```

And If I don't declare it `async` I am not able to use `await`.

Isn't there some king of `get()` method that just synchronously wait for a Promise to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a reason why cypress is so restrictive about what you can do about waiting for async method to resolve: it always automatically runs all the async commands in sequential order, as they are called, not in parallel, so this will execute in the right order even if `createUser` is Async :

```
Cypress.Commands.add("populateDb", (users) => {
  for (const user in users) {
    cy.createUser(user).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
})
```

If you want to get the value of what is returned (in my case, I need the user ID to delete them later), you can just store them in a `var` at file root level and add a cypress command that returns that var.

```
var createdItems = []

Cypress.Commands.add("getCreatedItems", () => {
  return createdItems
})

Cypress.Commands.add("populateDb", (users) => {
  for (const user in users) {
    cy.createUser(user).then(response => {
      createdItems.unshift(response) // I unshift() because I need to delete them in FILO order later
    })
  }
})
```

Then in the cypress test file you can just call them in the order you need them to execute :

```
cy.populateDb(users)
cy.getCreatedItems().then(response => {
  //response is my createdItems Array, and cy.getCreatedItems() will run only when cy.populateDb() is resolved
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `wrap` and `each` cypress command I was able to achieve a loop that waits for each iteration and can return the full results without needing a global variable.

The only reason I use the `wrap` command is because the cypress command `each` requires it to be chained off a previous cypress command. The `each` command will evaluate each iteration and finally call the `then` where you can return the complete results array. I am using this to upload multiple files and return the list of keys, but you can modify this for your own need.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("uploadMultipleFiles", (files) => {
    var uploadedS3Keys = []
    cy.wrap(files).each((file, index, list) => {
        cy.uploadFileToOrdersApi(file)
            .then(s3Key => uploadedS3Keys.push(s3Key))
    }).then(() => uploadedS3Keys)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it also like:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("populateDb", (users) => {
  for (const user in users) {
    cy.createUser(user).then(response => {
      createdItems.unshift(response) // I unshift() because I need to delete them in FILO order later
    })
  }

  return createdItems;
})

cy.populateDb(users).then(response => {
  // ... runs after populate ...
})
```

But the other answer is also right. Each `cy.xxxxx` command is actually added to command queue and ran one after each other. If during queue execution new `cy.xxxxx2` commands are called, they will be added to front of the queue.

Here is simple example to explain the execution order of cypress command queue and synchronous code:

```
const a = 1; // a == 1

cy.cmd1().then(() => {
  cy.cmd2().then(() => {
    a += 1; // a == 5
  });

  a += 1; // a == 3

  cy.cmd3()
  a += 1; // a == 4
});

cy.cmd4().then(() => {
  a += 1; // a == 6
});

a += 1; // a == 2

// at this point cypress command queue starts running the queue that is cmd1, cmd4

// 1. cmd1 runs and adds cmd2 and cmd3 to front of command queue also adds +2 to a
// 2. cmd2 runs and adds +1 to a
// 3. cmd3 runs
// 4. cmd4 runs and adds +1 to a
// ... all done ...
```

So from this example you can see that in your case you loop will be executed serially, because each `cy.createUser` is added to cypress command queue and executed then sequentially.