# Node.js Fetch Remote Files and Concatenate and Save Them Locally

Tags: node.js

Below works but it looks like I'm missing little chunks of data. What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do here. I run `node updateFiles.js 5.5.9` and it's lightning fast but like I said, when I eyeball the result file, it appears I miss some chunks...?

Below is the contents of `updateFiles.js`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var version = process.argv[2];
var filePath = 'source/js/firebase.js';
var sdks = [
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-app.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-auth.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-database.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-firestore.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-messaging.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-functions.js'
]; 

//fetch each firebase file and write it to source/js/firebase.js
for (var sdk of sdks){
    fetch(sdk).then(res => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath,{flags:'a'});
        res.body.pipe(dest);
    });    
}
```

UPDATE: I ended up doing this and it seems to work, but, if there's a guru out there that can indicate a better way please let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var version = process.argv[2];
var promisesArray = [];
var sdks = [
// Firebase App is always required and must be first
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-app.js',
// Add additional services that you want to use
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-auth.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-database.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-firestore.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-messaging.js',
'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/' + version + '/firebase-functions.js'
];

var filePath = 'source/js/firebase.js'; 

for (var sdk of sdks){
    promisesArray.push(fetch(sdk));
}

Promise.all(promisesArray).then(sdkFiles => {
    for (var file of sdkFiles){
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath,{flags:'a'});
        file.body.pipe(dest);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cannot write all files at once but wait for each file to be processed and then continue with another one? The promise for loop is taken from: [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop)

```
for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < sdks.length; i++) {
  p = p.then(_ => new Promise(resolve =>
    fetch(sdks[i]).then(res => {
      const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, { flags: 'a' });
      res.body.pipe(dest);
      resolve()
    })
  ));
}
```

Comment: True. ...I'm just trying to do it the best possible way, or the "Node way", or the advanced way as shown [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#streams). Realistically and practically, I could do that, although Promise.all might be slightly faster (parallel)