# Wait for the end of a function each time it runs in a loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to call a function and wait for it to end. I tried to use an example that works well (in the case of one call) using promises.

```
function firstFunction(layer)
{
    // I want to make some requests to my server which i don't know how much time it'll take
    console.log(layer + ' in firstFunction');
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
}

function secondFunction()
{
    var layers=['layer1','layer2','layer3'];
    var promise = null;
    layers.forEach(function(layer,idx,array) {
        promise = firstFunction(layer);
        promise.then(function(result) { 
            if (idx === array.length - 1){ 
                console.log(layer ' is the last layer in secondFunction');
            }
            else{
                console.log(layer+' in secondFunction');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

what I am expecting is this :

```
layer1 in firstFunction
layer1 in secondFunction
layer2 in firstFunction
layer2 in secondFunction
layer3 in firstFunction
layer3 is the last layer in secondFunction
```

but I am getting this :

```
layer1 in firstFunction
layer2 in firstFunction
layer3 in firstFunction
layer1 in secondFunction
layer2 in secondFunction
layer3 is the last layer in secondFunction
```

EDIT : 
I'm avoiding setTimeout because I'm afraid that my function will need more than the time I gave.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I tried to avoid setTimeout because I'm afraid that my fonction will need more than the time I gave. don't you think that this is a problem ?