# Function returns before ajax call in for loop end

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I'm having some trouble with a function that returns before ajax call from for loop ends. I do several ajax call which I get the result from and use them on my  then chain.

Here is my code

```
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
(async () => {
    await delay(timeout);
    let results: boolean[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        await this.ajaxService.postWithData("/api/v1/..",
            arg,
            (data) => {
                results[i] = this.checkStep(data);
            },
            () => {
            });
    }
    return results; // This returns before for loop containing ajaxServces calls ends
})().then((results) => {
    // Do some things here using `results`
});
```

**postWithData**

```
public request = (options: Options, successCallback: Function, errorCallback?: Function): void => {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: options.url,
            type: options.method,
            data: options.data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (d) {
                successCallback(d);
            },
            error: function (d) {
                if (errorCallback) {
                    errorCallback(d);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I've checked SO answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329190/3264998

Comment: `ajaxService.postWithData()` must return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in order for [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to actually pause execution until the request is complete. Right now, it doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `request` wrapper is not great and unfortunately Aaron's isn't much better. I haven't used jQuery much in recent years, but I think it has Promise-based APIs now too. Either way you'll want something generic that basically gives you a "promisified" version of `$.ajax` so you can work with `await` -

```
const defaultOpts =
  { method: 'GET', cache: false }

const request = (opts = {}) =>
  new Promise
    ( (resolve, reject) =>
        $.ajax({ ...defaultOpts, ...opts })
         .done((req, status, res) => resolve(res))
         .fail((req, status, err) => reject(err))
    )
```

You haven't provided a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it makes it difficult help you. We don't know about `times` or `checkStep` so some guesses were made about your intentions. Something like this might help get your wheels turning again -

```
const main = async () =>
{ const steps =
    [ request ("/api/v1/something..")
    , request ("/api/v1/another..")
    , request ("/api/v2/andthis..")
    ]

    const res =
      await Promise.all(steps)

   console.log(res)
    // [ <result1>, <result2>, <result3> ]

    // I don't know what your checkStep does
    // but something like this might work
    res.forEach(r => this.checkStep(r))

    // otherwise
    // const checked =
    //   res.map(r => this.checkStep(r))
    // ...

    return res
}

main()
  .then(res => console.log("all results", res))
  // [ <result1>, <result2>, <result3> ]
  .catch (e => ...)
```

If one request is dependent on another, putting the requests in an array and then calling `Promise.all` is not a great fit. In the example below we query all the posts for a particular author. The fictional API we're querying asks for the author's `username` but we only know the author's `id`. In this case, we look up the author's username first, *then* we can query the posts by username -

```
const authorById = id =>
  request({ url: '/authors', data: { id } })

const postsByAuthor = username =>
  request ({ url: '/posts', data: { author: username } })

const main = () =>
{ const author =
    await authorById (10)
    // { id: 10, username: alice, email: alice@email.lol }

  // this request depends on the result of the first request
  const posts =
    await postsByAuthor (author.username)
    // [ { postId: 9, title: "hello world" }, { postId: 11, ... }, ... ]

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems theres a problem when mapping. `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<{}[]>'`

Comment: @GeraldHughes I try to include a functional code snippet in all of my answers but in the case of your question here, too much information was missing to make that possible. I fixed the `.map` mistake and updated my answer with my best guesses at your intentions. I hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
public request = (options: Options, successCallback: Function, errorCallback?: Function): Promise => {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: options.url,
            type: options.method,
            data: options.data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (d) {
                resolve(successCallback(d));

            },
            error: function (d) {
                if (errorCallback) {
                    reject(errorCallback(d));

                }
            }
        })};
    }
```

Also, you specified a return type for your function, would you be using TypeScript? Not sure if Promise return type is valid. But the idea is that you need to return a promise.