# How to close MySQL connection after multiple promise?

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I have to use multiple SQL request. So I create a Promise to do this. But I need to use this promise into the same promise. When I try to stop my SQL connection with "connection.end()", I have this error in my console :
**Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.**

If I don't write "connection.end()", my code works.

```
function requete( sql ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        this.connection.query( sql, ( err, rows ) => {
            if ( err )
                return reject( err );
            resolve( rows );
        } );
    } );
}

myRouter.route('/profil/verifBadge')
.get(function (req, res) {

    var tabBadgeAjoute  =   [];
    var tabVerifBadge   =   [];

    //Etape 1 
    requete("my SQL request")
    .then( (rows) => {
        if (rows.length != 0){
            for (let competence of rows){
                if (competence.TotalLike >=5)    { tabVerifBadge.push("one SQL request"); tabBadgeAjoute.push(myString)}
                if (competence.TotalLike >=10)   { tabVerifBadge.push("one SQL request"); tabBadgeAjoute.push(myString)}
                if (competence.TotalLike >=25)   { tabVerifBadge.push("one SQL request"); tabBadgeAjoute.push(myString)}
                if (competence.TotalLike >=100)  { tabVerifBadge.push("one SQL request" ); tabBadgeAjoute.push(myString)}
            }
        }

    })
    //Etape 2 
    .then( () => {
        for (let requeteSQL in tabVerifBadge){
            requete(tabVerifBadge[requeteSQL].toString())
            .then( (rows2) => {
                if (rows2.length == 0){
                    requete("one SQL request")
                    .then(() => console.log("ok")
                    .catch( err => console.dir(err));
                };
            })
            .catch( err => console.dir(err));
        }

    })
    .then( () => 
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": "ok"}))
    )
    .then((rows) => connection.end())
    .catch( err => {
        // handle the error
        console.dir(err);
    })



 })
```

Comment: you're closing the connection before doing the queries.

Comment: Yes I have understand that. But I write the "connection.end()" command on the last "then" of the Promise. Apparently, it's not here I have to write it. Do you know where I must write "connection.end()"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a `for...of` loop in your first Promise and a `for...in` loop in your second Promise. You can't guarantee that the queries in these two Promises will be completed when you call the last `.then()` to close the connection.

Try something like that:

```
.then(async function() {
    for (let requeteSQL in tabVerifBadge){
        await requete(tabVerifBadge[requeteSQL].toString())
            .then( (rows2) => {
                //...
            })
            .catch( err => console.dir(err));
    }
})
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40328932/5156280) for alternative methods.