# Javascript code to do clicks by Id and by Xpath executes so fast

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I'm very new to Javascript. I try to set a javascript code in Selenium IDE with "execute Script" command in order to open a settings button that share the same class="MyClass" (there are 16 buttons).

After clicking the button appears a window with some options. When these options are visible I want to click the option that can be located by Xpath,
and finally I want to save the settings for each button, then repeat the same for the 16 buttons.

The code I have so far it seems to work partially, because locates the 16 button and I can do the for loop and click on them, but it seems that runs so fast
and this generates that the other actions don't be completed.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass"); 
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].click(); // To open each button that have the class = "MyClass"
    document.evaluate(" //li[contains(.,'sometext')] ", document.body, null, 9, null). singleNodeValue.click(); // Click on elemenet by Xpath
    document.getElementById("savesettings").click(); // Save settings
};
```

How can I add some pause for example like this?

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass"); 
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].click(); // To open each button that have the class = "MyClass"

    **Command to wait 2 seconds**

    document.evaluate(" //li[contains(.,'sometext')] ", document.body, null, 9, null). singleNodeValue.click(); // Click on elemenet by Xpath

    **Command to wait 2 seconds**

    document.getElementById("savesettings").click(); 
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you're trying to do here but you can delay the execution by utilizing the **window.setTimeout** function. This will trigger a function after a pre-determined amount of time.

Inside this function you can decide what to do - initiate another timout or execute something right-away - with a simple switch-block.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass");
var currentItem = 0;
var currentAction = 0;

function update() {
  switch (currentAction) {
    case 0:
      items[currentItem].click();
      currentAction = 1;
      window.setTimeout(update, 2000);
      break;
    case 1:
      document.evaluate(" //li[contains(.,'sometext')] ", document.body, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click(); // Click on elemenet by Xpath
      currentAction = 2;
      window.setTimeout(update, 2000);
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("savesettings").click();
      currentAction = 0;
      if (currentItem + 1 < items.length) {
        currentItem++;
        update();
      }
      break;
  }
}

update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

There is an answer here: [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop/40329190)

You can take the example there and implement it inside your code:

```
for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
    p = p.then(_ => new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000)
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't see a easy way to adapt your example to my code.