# chaining promise JS with forloop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I am trying to learn how to chain promise with JS. I saw the code here and they did it with a forloop [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop/40329190). I found it to be cool and decided to try it with small adjustments. But it failed to work. I will really appreciate it if you can tell me why this doesn't work

Here's my code:

```
//Goal: print from 0-10 in order at random times
function test() {
    for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
        p = p.then(createPromise(i));
    }
}

function createPromise(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000)
    )
}

test();
```

Here's the output of my code

```
9
1
7
8
0
6
3
2
5
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` needs a *callback*, not a Promise - at the moment, you're calling `createPromise(i)` *immediately*, inside the loop. Create a function that, when called, *returns* a Promise instead:

```
p = p.then(() => createPromise(i));
```

```js
function test() {
    for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
        p = p.then(() => createPromise(i));
    }
}

function createPromise(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000)
    )
}

test();
```