# How to run setTimeout synchronously in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await, settimeout

Here's a while loop that calls Google's geocode API every iteration.  I want to slow down the frequency that the API is called by waiting 5-10 seconds before the while loop repeats again.  Because setTimeout is asynchronous, I have it being resolved as a promise so that I can await for `timeout`, but the behavior I get is that `setTimeout` executes even before `covertToAddresses` fxn is called.  What I've also tried is converting the while loop into `setInterval` which had the consequence of ignoring await altogether.  I would really like to understand why this implementation doesn't work.

```
async function convertToAddress() {
    await axios.get(reverseGeoCodeURL).then(res => {
        let ranAddr = res.data.results[0].formatted_address
        let corrCity = new RegExp(`, ${city},`, 'i');
        // before adding the address to an array to be added
        // make sure it's a Soutlake address
        
        if (corrCity.exec(ranAddr)) {
            transPredtoJSON(ranAddr)
            count += 1
            console.log('count', count);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('error: ', error);
    })
}

function timeout() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve('waiting for 10 seconds'), 10000));

(async function run() {
    while (count < enoughAddresses) { 
        randomCoordinate = randomGeo({ latitude: originlat, longitude: originlng }, radius)

        lat = randomCoordinate.latitude
        lng = randomCoordinate.longitude
        reverseGeoCodeURL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${result.parsed.GEOCODE_API_KEY}
       
        await convertToAddress(reverseGeoCodeURL)
        await timeout().then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    }
})()
```

Comment: It is not possible that `setTimeout` is called before `convertToAddress`. Your `run` function will execute `convertToAddress` and return a promise.

Comment: Does `covertToAddresses` return a promise which you can `await`?

Comment: The console log in `timeout` sometimes prints before or sometimes multiple times after the console log that is inside `convertToAddress`.

Comment: @Bergi, yes convertToAddresses does return a promise that I'm awaiting which works fine without the timeout fxn

Comment: I've tried invoking `timeout` inside the .then of convertToAddresses, but I still get the same behavior

Comment: @AaronJan But then `covertToAddresses` is broken if it prints a console log *after* fulfilling the returned promise. Please [edit] your question to include that code

Comment: Replace `convertToAddress` with a `console.log`.  I'm betting that your issue is in `convertToAddress`, not `timeout`.  Also you don't need to await the Promise inside of the `timeout` if you're awaiting in `run`.  Just return the Promise in `timeout`.

Comment: @trincot I don't think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop solves the OP's problem. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop, but it seems there's something else at play here (it rather should be closed for lacking debugging info).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kkaung/645c812891c09062a8621a3efbb9365a

Comment: I implemented your solution @KevinAung; and message got console logged several times before the log in `convertToAddresses` like before.  So perhaps the problem is in `convertToAddresses`, which I've edited the Q to include @Bergi

Comment: replacing `convertToAddresses` with a console log does produce console logs in the correct order.  So I'll look into this fxn to fix the problem. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: @AaronJan The `convertToAddresses` looks fine (although the `.then` syntax should be replaced by `await`). Are you really saying the `console.log('count', count);` occurs after the `console.log('waiting for 10 seconds')`?

Comment: this is exactly what I get:

Comment: ```
waiting for 10 seconds \
waiting for 10 seconds \
waiting for 10 seconds \
waiting for 10 seconds \
waiting for 10 seconds \
waiting for 10 seconds \
count 1 \
waiting for 10 seconds \
count 2 \
waiting for 10 seconds
....
```