# Correct asynchronous loop analog for for-await-of

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await, eslint

I have a asynchronous loop for getting payload:

```
let payload = "";
for await (const chunk of body) {
  payload += chunk;
}
```

But this code is no supported by ESLint:

> error  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations  no-restricted-syntax

How to implement **for-await-of** to supported loop format by ESLint, eg. forEach(), map(), reduce()? As asynchronous function?

Comment: Is `body` an array?

Comment: Is `body` an array of promises?

Comment: Yes, this example code was taken from the official documentation for elasticsearch client: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/as_stream_examples.html

Comment: Just move the `await` keyword between `+=` and `chunk`. You can use any of the alternatives posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329190/5459839).