# Unable to Resolve Promise in forEach

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

This is the code where I'm calling a function

```
masterCredsResponse.data.forEach((masterCred) => {
  // Check Login status
  masterCredsArray.push({
    master: masterCred.parent,
    loginCheck: Promise.resolve(getSessionID()())
  })
})
```

Here I get

```
loginCheck: Promise { <pending> }
```

I'm seeing a lot of questions on this topic but unable to understand how to get it done.
When I don't use loop but call it separately then it works
like

```
let loginCheckReponse =  await getSessionID()()
```

But i use this method in a loop that doesn't work

```
loginCheck: await getSessionID()() // Doesn't work
```

Comment: what does *Doesn't work* mean? Please describe errors fully

Comment: Means it returns Promise { <pending> }

Comment: if `getSessionID()()` results in a Promise, then `Promise.resolve(getSessionID()())` doesn't do anything useful (like wait for it to settle)

Comment: You misunderstand what `Promise.resolve` does. It wraps an already found value inside of a new `Promise` that immediately `resolve`s, meaning the data is able to be accessed. It doesn't mean that it doesn't make it a `Promise` anymore. You still need to either `await` or `.then` the `Promise`

Comment: And then moves to next iteration without returning actual response from getSessionID func

Comment: the clue is where you say `then it works like` ... that's what you need to do in a `for` loop, not in a `forEach` callback

Comment: There is some good information about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop

Answer (score 3):

@Samathingamajig is right about `Promise.resolve`. Also, you can't run `await` inside of the `forEach` without making the callback async.

The most basic fix would be adding an `async` to the callback and an `await` to the promise. But you then wouldn't be able to ergonomically wait for the array to finish processing.

```
masterCredsResponse.data.forEach(async (masterCred) => {
  masterCredsArray.push({
    master: masterCred.parent,
    loginCheck: Promise.resolve(getSessionID())
  })
})
```

You can use `map` and `Promise.all` to make sure you block execution properly. Note that they will all occur in parallel:

```js
const masterCredPromises = masterCredsResponse.data.map(
  async (masterCred) => ({
    master: masterCred.parent, 
    loginCheck: await getSessionId()
  })
);
const masterCredsArray = await Promise.all(masterCredPromises);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So you mean the solution will Promise.all() will work faster then others ? due to parallel in  nature

Answer (score 1):

```
masterCredsResponse.data.forEach( async (masterCred) => {
  let loginCheckReponse =  await getSessionID()()
  // Check Login status
  masterCredsArray.push({
    master: masterCred.parent,
    loginCheck: loginCheckReponse
  })
})
```